# Static site generator for presenting an overview of projects on a single page

Tags: static-site-generator

I'm looking for a static site generator that I can use for a website that will present some projects I am working on.

Each project will have these things:

- Title (text)
- Description (text)
- Project status (text, or better: category for filtering)
- Link to github repo (link)
- Short description of help needed with the project (text)
- Download link (link to file)
- Screenshot (ideally an image on the page, otherwise a link is okay also)

I don't want a page to be generated for each project, I just want this short overview for each project, presented close to each other.

What can you recommend that I look at? Grateful for help!

Comment: This sounds like it would be straightforward to do by writing the HTML and CSS by hand. Are you sure you would benefit from a static-site generator?

Comment: Kodoiologist: Thank you for your question, I've been thinking the same thing and for now that is what i'm doing, I'm hoping though that there is something out there easy to use so I don't have to duplicate the html, but maybe the benefit of avoiding duplication isn't enough compared with having to rely on another tool

Comment: So the benefit you're interested in, basically, is not having to copy and paste the HTML for each project? HTML is expressive enough that hopefully there won't be much to copy, but that is indeed the sort of thing a static-site generator could help you with. Even a template engine alone (which is usually one part of a static-site generator) could achieve this, whether an HTML-specific system like Haml or a generic template system like Perl's Text::Template or Python's `str.format()`.

Comment: Yes I'd like to avoid copy+paste, I will look at template engines and `str.format()` (I've been programming in Python lately so am happy to use this). Thank you for these tips!